# Run .lua script for Telegram from shell vs cmd

Tags: python, lua, sh, raspberry-pi3, telegram

I dont get why, but i cant run same command from script and cmd to have same result. (Problem on my RPi3)

When i run:

```
cd tg
bin/telegram-cli -k tg-server.pub -W -s action4.lua
```

My telegram works very fine! All is ok.
Problem is when i try to do this from any script that i can set to be booted up.
Here is my `start.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
tgpath=/home/pi/tg
cd ${tgpath}
cmd="bin/telegram-cli -k tg-server.pub -W -s action4.lua"
eval $cmd
```

This cause:

```
change_user_group: can't find the user telegramd to switch to
```

And my Telegram-cli dont want to do anything.

I've read so many forums and still dont know how to manage it. Only simple command from command line works. not even a single script to run it properly.

My app works great to take photo, record video on command or from PIR sensor.
I would like to have chance to reset my app by remote from anywhere.

Any suggestions how to change it?

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:python]?

Comment: Cal you `ls -l` for those file?

Comment: How do you execute `start.sh`? This error looks like it is coming from something else, like a systemd unit.

Comment: i tagged it with python becuse i use python all the way. Lua and SH are addictionally. I execute start.sh by sudo ./start.sh